# Existence of nets from weak closure

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence, nets

Hi I am interested in the following question.

Given some normed space $X$ with a subset $S \subset X$. If I consider $x \in \text{wcl}(S)$, where 'wcl' denotes the weak closure of $S$, then since the weak topology is not necessarily first-countable I can't state that there exists a sequence in $S$ such that $$x_{n} \rightharpoonup x~~~n \in \mathbb{N}$$ Can I alternatively state that there exists a net in $S$ such that $$x_{i} \rightharpoonup x~~~i \in I$$ If I can, then what would my directed set $I$ be defined as? Would any additional assumptions assist?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Define the directed set using an nhood base at $x$, as defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29#Examples_of_nets).